# Why are words like bottom, forty, fifty, one, etc classified as stop words?

Tags: spacy

Why are important words like bottom, forty, fifty, one, etc which may provide contextual information classified as stop words in spacy?

Comment: I guess it was set based on the frequency of top `n` words. You might want to change [this](https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/blob/master/spacy/lang/en/stop_words.py) to remove words from the stopword list.